# C# Winform UI freezes after some time if following conditions are met

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, freeze

I have been spending some sleepless nights over this problem and I can't seem to figure out why. I would so much appreciate any help from the community.

I have a Winforms application which freezes after some time (5-10 min typically) after having performed following actions :

1) When I push a button which starts a separate UI thread creating a WPF modal dialogue   AND

2) when this WPF modal dialogue creates another Winforms modal dialogue

Note: Main Winforms application freezes after some time after having performed 1) and 2) (sometime after these tasks are completed and the thread associated with 1 is destoyed).

Also note: that when 1) and 2) happens in a separate process instead of thread, then Winforms application doesn't freeze after some time. Moreover if 2) doesn't happen, then also there is no application freeze. Also, I tried 2) with an empty Winform modal dialogue with no code and it still causes the issue

On Debugging:

After froze, following info is seen on callstack

1) Main Application thread is waiting on  DispatcherOperation.WaitOne() with no upper call stack available

Comment: From the error it is clear that the Thread in question is waiting infinitely and fails to process UI events. Refer to Application.DoEvents(); WinForms and find out what is similar in case of WPF. This may lead to some information on why your UI gets freezed

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more ? Do you want me to somehow call Application.DoEvents() while the thread is deadlocked ? If yes, then how should I get control flow to execute Application.DoEvents() in that state ?  In my investigation so far, main thread gets deadlocked due to point 2) of my post but I can't imagine how

Comment: WinForm and WPF both have Message loops which keep processing all the messages and act accordingly. One such important message is UI related and they need to be processed without blocking. WPF uses Dispatchers and Application.DoEvents() in WinForms keeps the UI response to it's events otherwise it will go white (hung). Refer to WndProc to get a gist of the message loop.

Comment: All I'm trying to say is, review your code and find out whether you're unknowingly blocking the UI thread.